# Unattend.xml - FirstLogonCommands - Only the first will run?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I'm building a win10 machine via USB but when it boots the first time to the desktop, only the first script would run (the Pop out notification), Here is the snippet of my `Unattend.xml`:

```xml
<FirstLogonCommands>
    <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
    <Description>Pop out nOtification</Description>
    <Order>1</Order>
    <CommandLine>powershell Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework; [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Make sure the computer is connected to the unauth port before continuing!!')</CommandLine>
    <RequiresUserInput>true</RequiresUserInput>
    </SynchronousCommand>
    <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
    <Description>Rename and Join  Computer to Domain</Description>
    <Order>2</Order>
    <CommandLine>powershell Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic; $COMPNAME = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter New Name', 'Rename Computer'); $OLDNAME = hostname; $CRED = Get-Credential -Message 'Enter admin credential'; $OUPATH = 'OU=Windows10,OU=LTCP User Computers,DC=domainhere,DC=com'; write-host ' after a restart'"`n"; Add-Computer -DomainName "domain.com" -ComputerName $OLDNAME -NewName $COMPNAME -Credential $CRED -OUPath $OUPATH; write-host "`n"'Join sucessful, machine is in WIN10 OU.. restarting in 10s' -ForegroundColor Yellow; Start-Sleep 10; Restart-Computer</CommandLine>
    <RequiresUserInput>true</RequiresUserInput>
    </SynchronousCommand>
</FirstLogonCommands>
```

I have verified that the script runs fine in PowerShell ISE, Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Hi, I do not now if this is the trigger of your problem, but when you use hostname, you are calling another executabel, I recommend to use the environment variable that store the computer name: replace in your second script "hostname", insted use $env:COMPUTERNAME

Comment: Can you try replacing those two with simple code, like creating a file to narrow down the issue.

Comment: The problem you are having is with Windows Deployment and not specifically to the powershell code within the deployment config. I'm voting to move this question to [sf] where this issue would be better suited.

Comment: @JamesC. So do you think the "Get-Credential" cmdlet is causing this issue since its attempting to contact the server but somehow something went wrong?